# HLSL tile shader

Tags: textures, hlsl

How would I make this HLSL code tile my texture:

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;
float4x4 WorldInverseTranspose;

float4 AmbientColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float AmbientIntensity = 0.5;

float3 DiffuseLightDirection = float3(1, 0, 0);
float4 DiffuseColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float DiffuseIntensity = 1.0;

float Shininess = 200;
float4 SpecularColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float SpecularIntensity = 1;
float3 ViewVector = float3(1, 0, 0);

texture ModelTexture;
sampler2D textureSampler = sampler_state {
    Texture = (ModelTexture);
    MinFilter = Point;
    MagFilter = Point;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float4 Normal : NORMAL0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
    float3 Normal : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD1;
};

VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);

    float4 normal = normalize(mul(input.Normal, WorldInverseTranspose));
    float lightIntensity = dot(normal, DiffuseLightDirection);
    output.Color = saturate(DiffuseColor * DiffuseIntensity * lightIntensity * 0);

    output.Normal = normal;

    output.TextureCoordinate = input.TextureCoordinate;
    return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    float3 light = normalize(DiffuseLightDirection);
    float3 normal = normalize(input.Normal);
    float3 r = normalize(2 * dot(light, normal) * normal - light);
    float3 v = normalize(mul(normalize(ViewVector), World));
    float dotProduct = dot(r, v);

    float4 specular = SpecularIntensity * SpecularColor * max(pow(dotProduct, Shininess), 0) * length(input.Color);

    float4 textureColor = tex2D(textureSampler, input.TextureCoordinate);
    textureColor.a = 1;

    return saturate(textureColor * ((input.Color) + (AmbientColor * AmbientIntensity) + specular));
}

technique Textured
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_1_1 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

This the current result:

[image]

I want to tile this texture over the cube instead of stretching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output.TextureCoordinate = input.TextureCoordinate * 100;
```

It would tile it but I imagine you would probably want some controlled tiling? And for that you have to modify your uv texture coordinates by hand for every vertex.